# Adding textfile with --onefile option

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

the `--add-data` option works well without using `--onefile` option

I want the data text files to be compressed and merged into an exe file. But exe file only works when the data text file is in the same folder.

How can I merge the text file into the only one exe file??

When I used:

```
pyinstaller --add-data ="\GameUserSettings.ini;." file.py
```

it works.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data ="\GameUserSettings.ini;." file.py
```

it can make the `file.exe` but it doesn't work well. and it works only when the text file is in the same folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add your text file with `one-dir`, Pyinstaller would put your file next to your executable and you will be fine when accessing your file by the script (e.g `open("myfile.txt")`. But when you create your executable with `--onefile` it would extract your file in a temp directory which is a separate directory, so calling `open("myfile.txt")` would result in a `NotFound` error because the file doesn't exist besides your executable. So you need to change the path to point to the temp directory. The `sys._MEIPASS` would return the temp directory so you need to locate your files inside it. You can find more info in [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.4/runtime-information.html).

A function like this would solve the problem:

```
import sys
import os


def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)
```

Then you can access your file with `source = resource_path("myfile.txt")`.